# Does the percieved attraction of peers change significantly when living in a foreign culture?

Tags: physical-attraction, cross-cultural-psychology

**Observation:** After living 10 month in India me and other exchange students (subjectively) rated the attractiveness of Indians far higher than at the beginning of the stay.

**Hypothesis:** It (evolutionarily) makes sense to initially have a low attraction to strangers (<-> "do not fall in love with the enemy"), but to have a mechanism that lets the perceived attractiveness of people in your surroundings increase over time (<-> "procreate within new peer group").

**Question:** Is there a known psychological/biological effect that lets the attractiveness of humans with other ethnic background increase over time when living within this ethnic group?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  This is an interesting question.  Have you carried out any research yourself to try and answer the question?  What problems are you having with the research?  Please edit the question to provide links to research carried out and what problems you are having because as it stands, this question could be closed for ["Lack of prior research"](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277/7604)

Comment: No I did not carry out any research. As mentioned I have just observed this subjective effect with me and others. The point is exactly to find out if there is research or not or to perhaps motivate such research. What is the point in allowing questions only when prior research has been done?